# transmission-cli connected to peers but not downloading

Tags: screen, scripts, bittorrent, transmission

I'm using my Ubuntu-Server and transmission-cli to download torrents overnight. When I try to download the Ubuntu 12.04.5 Server torrent transmission connects to various peers, but doesn't download anything.

The given command is:

```
/usr/bin/screen -a -S rdownload_$torrent_name /usr/bin/transmission-cli -w "$target_directory" $remote_home/$torrent_name
```

This is the (screened) output:

```
transmission-cli 2.52 (13304)
[00:04:21.914] Transmission 2.52 (13304) started
[00:04:21.917] RPC Server: Adding address to whitelist: 127.0.0.1
[00:04:21.961] UDP: Failed to set receive buffer: requested 4194304, got 327680
[00:04:21.961] UDP: Please add the line "net.core.rmem_max = 4194304" to /etc/sysctl.conf
[00:04:21.961] UDP: Failed to set send buffer: requested 1048576, got 327680
[00:04:21.961] UDP: Please add the line "net.core.wmem_max = 1048576" to /etc/sysctl.conf
[00:04:21.961] DHT: Reusing old id
[00:04:21.965] DHT: Bootstrapping from 89 IPv4 nodes
[00:04:22.029] Saved "/home/pi/.config/transmission/torrents/ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso.859da4d7affd6efd.torrent"
[00:04:22.249] Port Forwarding (NAT-PMP): initnatpmp succeeded (0)
[00:04:22.251] Port Forwarding (NAT-PMP): sendpublicaddressrequest succeeded (2)
[00:04:22.274] Port Forwarding (UPnP): Found Internet Gateway Device "http://192.168.178.1:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1"
[00:04:22.275] Port Forwarding (UPnP): Local Address is "192.168.178.33"
[00:04:22.295] Port Forwarding (UPnP): Port forwarding through "http://192.168.178.1:49000/igdupnp/control/WANIPConn1", service "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1". (local address: 192.168.178.33:51413)
[00:04:22.297] Port Forwarding: State changed from "Not forwarded" to "Starting"
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 0 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]          [00:04:22.979] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: Could not connect to tracker
[00:04:22.981] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: Retrying announce in 303 seconds.
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 36 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 61 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]         [00:04:30.027] Port Forwarding: State changed from "Starting" to "???"
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 61 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]         [00:04:33.001] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: Starting IPv4 DHT announce (poor, 16 nodes)
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 60 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]         [00:04:51.198] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: Scrape error: Could not connect to tracker
[00:04:51.198] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: Retrying scrape in 910 seconds.
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 60 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]         [00:08:13.782] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: IPv4 DHT announce done
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 60 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]         [00:09:25.536] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: Could not connect to tracker
[00:09:25.537] ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso: Retrying announce in 1815 seconds.
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 48 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]   [00:10:30.114] Saved "/home/pi/.config/transmission/resume/ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso.859da4d7affd6efd.resume"
Progress: 0.0%, dl from 0 of 53 peers (0 kB/s), ul to 0 (0 kB/s) [None]
```

In the download destination no directories are building up. The strange thing is, that another torrent from earlier today worked fine. But I didn't launched it via screen, though. Any ideas about possible reasons?

Thanks in regard,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

It works now. I think, I know why.
I accidentally executed transmission-cli once with the option -d but no value given. Could it be that this means download speed = 0?
When I gave the option -D it worked as expected.

Comment: Also worth noticing that if you paste a magnet link, ensure you enclose it in quotes.